# owncloud with setup-owncloud.php installation not working

Tags: owncloud

There is a possibility to install Owncloud with a php script setup-owncloud.php.
I have uploaded this file to my domain.
and startet the script with the Webbrowser.
I found out it has downloaded the files to the server, so far the script is working.
then it will request a admin name/pwd a db name, db user and db pwd.
I add this information hit the next button - then nothing happen except a white page (no error, no Information)

if i go to www.domain.com/owncloud/ 
the starting page come requesting again a admin name/pwd a db name, db user and db pwd

so the information are not stored nor the page corectly started

thanks for feedback
have a nice day
vinc

Answer (score 2):

I think your file is not named correctly.  The setup file with your values for database, etc, is

```
config/config.php
```

Comment: Thanks this hint should help! the content of the config.php file is just

<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'instanceid' => '525af2e359b11',
  'passwordsalt' => '41abcbfc3c740c32a3add15073578e',
);

Comment: You are welcome.  Please mark the question answered if you think it is complete.